# Custom errors: Application_Error vs web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net

What advantage does one technique have over the other:

1. Use Application_Error to handle
   exceptions or errors.
2. Use defaultredirect in the web.config
   file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other advantages or disadvantages, but the first thought that comes to mind is using Application_Error you are able to trap and log the error.

Comment: Thanks. If we have our custom logging it would be useful.